# Picking up the DB name in a line of a config file

Tags: text-processing, xml

I have this jdbc file line

```
<url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.70:1521:MYDBORA</url>
```

I need to use some kind of utility to catch  the `MYDBORA` part but it is not always the same name. I need the part between `1521:` and `</url>`

- I have tried

  ```
  grep 1521 config_file.xml | sed 's/.*://' |grep -o -P '.0,6</url'
  ```

  I get nothing in return
  *I also tried:

  ```
  grep 1521 config_file.xml | cut -d ':' -f 6
  ```

  I get

  ```
  MYDBORA<url>
  ```

I only want the name of the DB, not always 5 characters but everything between `1521:` and `<url>`

File extract:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc-data-source xmlns="xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source">
  <name>assetmanagement-xa-ds</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.70:1521:DB_NAME</url>
    <driver-name>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</driver-name>
    <properties> 
...
```

Comment: part of the file:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jdbc-data-source xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/jdbc-data-source">
  <name>assetmanagement-xa-ds</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.70:1521:DB_NAME</url>
    <driver-name>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</driver-name>
    <properties>

Comment: it is part of a weblogic JDBC file called assetmanagement-xa-ds-jdbc.xml

Comment: Please don't add questions to your post. If you receive an answer that works for you _for the question as originally asked_, then accept the answer and if you have further questions, then please ask them separately as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using a dedicated parser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658197/22222) is always the safer, more robust option, but here's another solution that will work unless your data are much more variable than you show:

```
$ grep -oP '<url>.*:\K[^<]+' file
MYDBORA
```

Comment: this worked but i posted at the beginning it fails when i try to execute remotely from another server than you for your help

Comment: @NickG. please post a new question if you have follow-up questions. However, based on your code, you were using two `'` instead of double quotes (`"`), that isn't the same thing. So try `ssh  -t app_user@192.168.2.1 "grep -oP '<url>.*:\K[^<]+' /webapps/application/domain/config/jdbc/assetmanagement-xa-ds-jdbc.xml"`

Answer (score 5):

Since this is JDBC and you're handling an XML file, you can use `xmlstarlet` to pick out the necessary element reliably without regard to whitespace or other irrelevant formatting

Using an example from the [JDBC documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12057_01/doc.1014/e12050/toplink.htm#BCGCBDJD), picking out `<connection-url/>` is as simple as this

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//connection-url' -n config_file.xml
jdbc:oracle:thin:@%hostname%:%port%:%database sid%
```

In your case you need to use `<url/>` instead of `<connection-url/>` so just substitute accordingly. You can then pick out the last colon:separated field

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//url' -n config_file.xml | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
MYDBORA
```

Comment: i do not seem to have xmlstarlet  installed.

Comment: To get rid of the `awk`: `... -m '//url' -v 'substring-after(.,"1521:")`

Comment: @NickG. There seems to be an obvious answer to that dilemma... :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

Starting with the jdbc-data-source.xml file from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39994984/7270649 , and using the `XML` module for Raku:

```
~$ raku -MXML -e 'my $xml=from-xml-file($*ARGFILES.Str); put $xml.elements(:TAG<url>, :RECURSE(Inf), :SINGLE);' jdbc-data-source.xml
<url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db</url>
```

It's then simple enough to extract individual data elements using `.contents.split(":")` :

```
~$ raku -MXML -e 'my $xml=from-xml-file($*ARGFILES.Str); put $xml.elements(:TAG<url>, :RECURSE(Inf), :SINGLE).contents.split(":");' jdbc-data-source.xml
jdbc oracle thin @host port db
```

Finally, just grab the last `db` element via indexing, for example with `.tail` or a numerical index such as `.[*-1]`. All-together now, as a Raku one-liner:

```
~$ raku -MXML -e 'my $xml=from-xml-file($*ARGFILES.Str); put $xml.elements(:TAG<url>, :RECURSE(Inf), :SINGLE).contents.split(":").tail;' jdbc-data-source.xml
db
```

https://raku.org/